# Issue with rendering two pure-CSS fancy checkboxes

Tags: css

I am trying to come up with a pure-CSS (without using third-party libraries) fancy checkboxes. And as long as I have to render one checkbox, the code seems to work fine. But when I add a second checkbox, the second element is rendered on top of the first one. And the second issue is concerned with label text. Any ideas ?

```css
.checkboxFive {
  position: relative;
}

.checkboxFive input {
  display: none;
}

.checkboxFive label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.checkboxFive label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.checkboxFive label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.checkboxFive input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxFive">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxFiveInput">Option 1</label>
</div>

<div class="checkboxFive">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxFiveInput">Option 2</label>
</div>
```

Here's the desired effect with one option case.

```css
.checkboxFive {
      position: relative;
    }

    .checkboxFive input {
      display: none;
    }

    .checkboxFive label {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      background: #eee;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .checkboxFive label:after {
      opacity: 0;
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 11px;
      height: 4px;
      background: transparent;
      border: 2px solid #333;
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }

    .checkboxFive label:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .checkboxFive input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="checkboxFive">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxFiveInput" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxFiveInput"></label>
 </div>
```

Comment: This is the downside of using `position: absolute;`

Comment: Yes, I know that. But how do I update the code to keep the desired effects and simultaneously get rid of the issue ?

Comment: something like this, https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your parent. you need to provide a padding/margin or a certain height to fix it.

```
.checkboxFive {
  position: relative;
  padding:10px;
  float:left
}
```

```css
.checkboxFive {
  position: relative;
  padding:10px;
  float:left
}

.checkboxFive input {
  display: none;
}

.checkboxFive label {
  content: '';
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.checkboxFive label:before {
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 11px;
  height: 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.checkboxFive label:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.checkboxFive input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxFive">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxFiveInput"></label>
</div>
<div class="checkboxFive">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxFiveInput"></label>
</div>
```